# Canvas to image in WinRT Code

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

In Win8 Metro apps i have a canvas it contains images and blocks and i want to save it to be displayed as an image using async, any idea with code?

Comment: If you want to create your own bitmap, you can take a look at WriteableBitmapEx (http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/)

Comment: thnx but it is not what i need.

Comment: I know, but it's the closest you're going to get to what you want :-S.

Comment: :)thnx man i will search more widely cuz this i try willnot work with my project at all .

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done I'm afraid - WinRT has no way to save xaml to an image.

Your best bet would be to handcraft your own bitmap, but it's a lot of work.

Sorry, I could have done with this functionality to!